# mysqldump Error 2013

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have a database installed, that I would like to backup  in mysql.  The problem  is `mysqldump` fails on exporting the 'maia_mail' table

```
# mysqldump -u root -p maia > maia.sql
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `maia_mail` at row: 15
```

It runs for less than 30 seconds and gets error out as above.

The total size of the DB is 1.3GB with the maia_mail table being 1.0GB

In `my.cnf` I have these set:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet      = 1300M
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet      = 1300M
```

Please advise or give some guidance on how to dump the database?

Comment: 170GB free space.  It's also the same whether I dump to machine db is on or remote

Comment: copies of email so varchar data mainly

Comment: the 1300M was a recent change, the problem existed when it was set to the default 16M too.   Server also had been restarted after the change to 1300M.

Comment: I set back to the 16M default.  dump results in the same error 2013 on row 15

Answer (score 16):

I could easily suggest changing InnoDB settings which might be a littel heavy-handed just to get a mysqldump to work. You may not like what I am about the suggest, but I believe it's your best (only) option. Here it goes:

## SUGGESTION #1 : Disable extended inserts

The default setting for mysqldump would include clumping together hundreds or thousands of rows in a single INSERT. This is known as an extended INSERT. [It is causing some overrun beyond just max_allowed_packet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/mysql-query-going-away-on-executing-insert-on-duplicate-update-statement-with/8260#8260).

I answered a post back on `Sep 01, 2011` ([MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323)) where I discussed doing the same thing for importing a large mysqldump. I believe disabling extended INSERT would help with creating a troublesome mysqldump as well.

```
mysqldump -u root --skip-extended-insert -p maia > maia.sql
```

Bad news: What this does in create an INSERT command for each row. This will definitely increase the time it takes to perform the mysqldump. Consequently, it will also increase to time is take to reload (probably by a factor of 10-100.

I have discussed `skip-extended-insert` before

- `Aug 12, 2011` : [Why is mysqldump file so large?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/why-is-mysqldump-file-so-large/4586#4586)
- `Aug 09, 2013` : [Backup / Export data from MySQL 5.5 attachments table keeps failing!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/backup-export-data-from-mysql-5-5-attachments-table-keeps-failing/47875#47875)
- `Nov 16, 2014` : [How to batch multiple insert statements for database dump with MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82774/how-to-batch-multiple-insert-statements-for-database-dump-with-mysql/82775#82775)

## SUGGESTION #2 : Dump binary data as hex (OPTIONAL)

To make the mysqldump's binary data more byte portable, [dump such data in hexadecimal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob)

```
mysqldump -u root --skip-extended-insert --hex-blob -p maia > maia.sql
```

Bad News: It will bloat the mysqldump a little more

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Side Note : [The maximum size of max_allowed_packet is 1G](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Answer (score 6):

I was also getting the same error while trying to dump 12 GB database. I did the following changes to make it work.

1. Configured max_allowed_packet to 1024M
2. Configured net_read_timeout to 7200
3. Configured net_write_timeout to 7200

Note: I know the time out values are way too high (7200 seconds ie 2 hours). But I did so itentionally just to rule out any chance. I am in the process of finding an optimal timeout value.

Comment: For other users: these are setting on the server, not in the mysqldump config file.  Also, 7200 seconds is 2 hours, not 20.

Comment: set global net_read_timeout = 120; 
set global net_write_timeout = 900; worked for me

Comment: Correction: 7200 seconds = 2 hours (not 20)

Answer (score 6):

Just include the following on your my.ini (Windows) or my.cnf (Linux) configuration file.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1024M 
net_read_timeout=3600 
net_write_timeout=3600

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=1024M
```

Comment: The sections should be the other way around.

Comment: I agree. This is the only solution that simply works!

Comment: This solution works - I think the key is that [mysqldump] section for the max_allowed_packet variable

Answer (score 4):

I found:

```
--max-allowed-packet=1G --net-buffer-length=32704
```

...makes it work where it didn't (reliably) previously, despite net read/write timeout changes, TCP keepalives etc.

The `max_allowed_packet` settings alone didn't make it work, so may not be required if `net_buffer_length` is used. - [ralph-bolton](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/37774/ralph-bolton)

Modifying `max-allowed-packet` and `net-buffer-length` seems much better than disabling extended inserts. - [kristofer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/33844/kristofer)

See also [What max_allowed_packet is big enough, and why do I need to change it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/what-max-allowed-packet-is-big-enough-and-why-do-i-need-to-change-it)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enough memory to take dump. Please keep checking memory while taking dump, e.g. using a command like this:

```
free -mt
```

If you memory exhaust while taking dump you will get

> mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection

Comment: Using `--quick` avoids using a buffer and thus running out of system memory.